# How to get one entry whose diffrence from current date and time is low

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have field data_clockin in table.what i want to find only last entry in data_chkin whose difference is minimum  from current data.for example today day,i have four entry but i want only one entry whose time is minimum  and if their is 4 entry in different date .i want only one entry whose difference is minimum or same from current date

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired results? Your word problem is very confusing and I'm sure I'm not the only one who wonders if the queries below actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE data_clockin = ( SELECT MAX(data_clockin) FROM Table )
```

Depending on the `data_clockin` values, this query may return **one row or multiple rows**.

Comment: I'd be careful with this one if you really only want one row. Did you try it against `AdventureWorks.Sales.SalesOrderHeader` for example? I get 39 rows.

Comment: @AaronBertrand +1 for your answer, because I am really not sure what the OP wants to achieve. I have just re-read the question a few more times and it does say that only *one entry* should be retrieved. I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP (1) cols
FROM dbo.unspecified_table_name
ORDER BY date_clockin DESC;
```

If you need to do this for multiple rows (say one row per group), then maybe:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT cols, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY some_grouping_key_column
    ORDER BY date_clockin DESC)
  FROM dbo.unspecified_table_name
)
SELECT cols FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
```